# How to frame a query using @Query annotation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

Is there any way to represent below query using spring-data mongo @Query annotation.

```
db.users.find({userName: "titogeo"}, {requests: 1, _id:0})
```

The above query output in console is

> requests" : [{"who" : "blahblahblah1",
>                 "whom" : "blahblahblah2",
>                 "what" : "REQUEST",
>                 "when" : ISODate("2012-09-05T17:52:14.339Z") } ] }

I tried the following but did not work.

```
@Query("{userName: ?0}, {requests:1, _id:0}")
public Page<AddRequest> getAllFriendRequests(String userName, Pageable pageable);
```

Collection users has User objects and requests is a list in it contains AddRequest objects.

When I execute the above method, i am getting a blank list. Any help is appreciated.

Also is there any good reference sites or books for spring-data-mongo apis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are using the filter property to restrict the set of properties that get returned (just requests), you need to use the property keywords in the following syntax:

```
@Query(value = "{ 'userName' : ?0 }", fields = "{ 'requests': 1, '_id': 0 }")
public Page<AddRequest> getAllFriendRequests(String userName, Pageable pageable);
```

Here is a helpful site for spring-data mongodb: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Thank you! I will try this in few hours and update the result. Does this JSON based @query methods have any disadvantages or advantages in terms of performance compared to other ways?

Comment: I tried the code, but not working. Still getting an empty list. I am invoking the method as follows `userDocumentRepository.getAllFriendRequests(userName, new PageRequest(0, 3));`